# Check an element through Selenium RC

Tags: selenium

Please suggest what logic should be used here through selenium RC.

Action
Check Close/Remove button.

Expected

In the upper-right corner of the app is a Close/Remove button.  This button only appears if there is at least one other app in the App Gallery module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"element position in upper right corner" -

```
Assert.assertTrue(getElementPositionLeft(buttonLocator).equal("some pixels"))
Assert.assertTrue(getElementPositionTop(buttonLocator).equal("some pixels"))
```

Notice that doing so also checks that element is present in page.

"This button only appears if there is at least one other app in the App Gallery module"

You could assert presence of app in app gallary module, when

```
isElementPrent("buttonLocator")
```

returns true.

Comment: Thanks a lot lot @Tarun, This is my understanding on this … getElementPositionLeft(buttonLocator).equal("some pixels")) ,As you mentioned in one of my x,y coordinate,  that first we check the element x and y position & store it in  variable. After that verify it on run time.  Is it OK?

Comment: One more thing for postion of an element check. We have this x,y coordinate in Selenium?

Comment: Please Comment..

Comment: I suppose x refer to left and y refer to top, hence getElementPositionLeft() would give you String object which you could compare with expected value. Same with getElementPositionTop.